# iOS data transfer via bluetooth audio profile

Tags: ios, bluetooth, file-transfer

I want to transfer some data from an embedded device to an iOS device using Bluetooth.

I am well aware that this is not possible using regular bluetooth serial communication as iOS devices does not implement any API to do this.

Here is what I collected from my researches :

- iOS devices support the following BT profiles (HFP,PBAP,A2DP,AVRCP,PAN,HID,MAP)

=> http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3647

- iOS most recent devices support Bluetooth Low Enery (Bluetooth Smart ready) devices although it is low rate transfer.
- iOS does NOT support data transfer using Bluetooth.

My questions is whether it is possible (or not) to use a bluetooth module within the range of accepted profiles in order to transfer data.

The idea would be the following : [image: Bluetooth audio profile file transfer]

Is this possible ?

Basically, the question is even simpler. Is it possible to record an audio stream coming from a bluetooth headset and save this stream to a file ?

Comment: were you ever able to find the solution to this problem?

Comment: So, how did you solve it?

Comment: I did not, unfortunately, solve this problem. I did not had time available at this period to implement a solution I was not even sure that would have worked. I basically just switched to Android